# MySql like query in JSON field

Tags: php, mysql

I have `JSON` type column named `medium` in my table

one of the field value like `["art", "nature"]`

I want to get the rows  with equivalent like query `WHERE`medium LIKE %art%`

Refered this links but can't find a proper solution for this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: Is this array or string...?

Comment: field is an array

Comment: How the data stored in the medium table ?

Answer (score 6):

You still can use `LIKE` with JSON fields. It is a valid solution if you want to include keywords in some generic search functionality.

What I've noticed so far but do not have an explanation for is that `LIKE` is case-sensitive when applied to JSON fields (at least it is happening in MySQL 5.7.24). To overcome this problem, you can convert JSON fields to strings and then use `LIKE`.

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE CONVERT(medium using 'utf8') LIKE '%art%';
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Just slap a lowercase() on the operands and it's finding the rows I want.

Answer (score -3):

I would advise not using a json type in this fashion. For one, JSON column types aren't that great for querying, they're a pita, and means you may be locked to one SQL implementation over another. Instead, you could either setup a separate table that contains a 1:n relationship with each record maintaining each of the mediums OR have a single column that has a comma-delimited string value with all the mediums. That then makes LIKE queries much easier and simpler - and indexable.